# Docker commit not saving files added to image

Tags: docker

I downloaded a docker image and want to add files to the image, such that I could save upload it to a remote server and it would still contain the files on start.

I've been reading that the accepted solution to this problem is to start the container, then use `docker cp` to add a file to the container, then use `docker commit` to create a new image containing these changes.  Unfortunately when I do this, the files I copied into the container are not saved. I'm trying to copy the files to a directory in my container called `/srv`.  (the files need to be here, so making a new dir/volume/etc might not solve my issue)

I've double and triple-checked that I'm copying correctly and committing the correct container.  I can verify with `docker exec` that the files are successfully copied into the container before committing.  They just don't persist in the newly created image.  I'm new to docker so I assume I have some fundamental misunderstanding about how the volumes handle these files, but without access to the dockerfile this image was created from, I'm not sure how to figure out what's happening to the files.  All similar issues I've read boiled down to either "use `docker cp` then `docker commit`" or "use a dockerfile", neither of which works for my issue.  Anything else I can check?

Comment: `docker commit` is pretty much never a best practice; writing a Dockerfile is almost always better.  (You can commit the Dockerfile to source control and easily regenerate the image if the original image ever updates, for example.)  Do you have a [mcve] demonstrating what you're trying to do?  If you're changing a directory the base image declared as a `VOLUME` or a directory you've `docker run -v` mounted into the container, that will never be persisted in an updated image.

Comment: Thanks David, your comment got me going in the right direction.  I did some more digging and found that I could list the image's various mounts by running ```docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' containerid``` and sure enough, the directory was set as a bind mount.